# How to change checked item in radiobutton group with buttons in windows forms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the checked item with buttons. For example, if I press the button 'right' item with the name 'right' becomes checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the TEXT in the Button matches EXACTLY (including case-sensitivity) the NAME property of the RadioButton.

All of your buttons could point to the same handler using code like this:

```
private void allButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    RadioButton rb = this.Controls.Find(btn.Text, true).FirstOrDefault() as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null)
    {
        rb.Checked = true;
    }
}
```